# Is there a rule for the pronunciation of words with the suffix -ative?

Tags: pronunciation, suffixes

I have observed that there are, at least, two patterns of pronunciation for words ending in *-ative*:

1. The first syllable is stressed and the suffix is pronounced as `/eɪtɪv/` (e.g. qualitative)
2. The second syllable is stressed and the suffix is pronounced as `/ətɪv/` (e.g. declarative)

Is there a way (other than memorizing them all, of course) to know how a certain word ending in *-ative* is pronounced?

Comment: Yes "qualitative" pronounced /'kwoliteitiv/ a US pronunciation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close. It depends on the stress of the syllable before the *-ative*. If there is primary or secondary stress, then you have an unstressed *a* in the *-ative*. Otherwise, the *a* would be stressed and get its full /ei/ sound. Note that some words have different pronunciation patterns in different dialects.

- NA-tive  (0 before)
- cre-A-tive (weak before)
- REL-a-tive (strong before)
- con-SERV-a-tive (weak-strong)
- LEG-i-SLA-tive  (strong-weak)
- RE-pre-SEN-ta-tive (strong-weak-strong)
- ad-MIN-i-STRA-tive (weak-strong-weak) but also ad-MIN-i-stra-tive

[Here](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=13756486) is a link to all the *-ative* words in the COCA.

Comment: Of course you have to know about the accent in the previous syllable... These are things noted by foreigners learning english.  Different accents in *declaration* and *declarative*.  But same accent in *quality* and *qualitative*.

Comment: Indeed, there's no getting away from the fact that some learning is involved. The rule probably just pushes the problem back another level, but it is what Otavio asked for.

Comment: Isn't */ˈkwɒlɪteitɪv/* (or */ˈkwɒlɪˌteitɪv/*) a US - or at least non British pronunciation-? I've heard */ˈkwɒlɪtətɪv/* in Britain.